# Representations for topological groups

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, representation-theory

The net difference between a smooth action of a topological group $G$ and a representation is the linearity in the space on which they act?

For $X$, say, a differentiable manifold we define the continuous maps:

$Action:G\to \operatorname{Diffeo}(X)$

$Repr:G\to \operatorname{Aut}(X)$              $\hspace{0.07cm}$?

Edit: linearity instead if invertibility, $Diffeo$ instead on $C^\infty$.

Comment: No, any action of a group in a category is the same as a homomorphism from $G$ to the group of the category isomorphisms. We generally don't write $G\to C^{\infty}(X)$ for actions.

Comment: I meant "linearity" sorry. Would that be correct to write that a smooth action is a continuous map from $G$ to the diffeomorphism group of $X$?

Comment: Use `$\operatorname{name}$` for $\operatorname{name}$.

Comment: What sorry @Shaun?

Comment: For example, `$\operatorname{Aut}(X)$` for $\operatorname{Aut}(X)$.

Comment: Sure, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

An action is by definition always by invertible operators. The difference is that a representation requires $X$ be a vector space and for $G$ to act on $V$ by linear operators.